# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' and ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, knn

```
Sample = [{'id': 1, 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': [[.332, .326], [.058, .138]]},
 {'id': 2,  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': [[.234, .246], [.234, .395]]},
 {'id': 3,  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': [[.084, .23], [.745, .923]]}]
df = pd.DataFrame(Sample)
df

df=df.assign(New=df[['Feb', 'Jan']].values.tolist())
```

Here I try to find K nearest neighbours from a dataframe

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10, algorithm='auto')
knn.fit(df['New'].to_numpy())

def get_neighbors(id):
    vector = df.loc[id]
    return knn.kneighbors([vector], 10, return_distance=False)
```

but a TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' is occur at line knn.fit(df['New'].to_numpy())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df=df.assign(New=df[['Feb', 'Jan']].values.tolist())
```

try with this line

```
New = df[['Feb', 'Jan']].values.tolist()
```